# Same question, different technology

Tags: support, stack-overflow, related-questions

I want to ask a question related to Android, but I found the same question, but tagged as [python](/questions/tagged/python). What should I do now? Can I ask the same question, but tagged with [android](/questions/tagged/android)?

The question I wanted to ask is "Convert a string in base64 to an image and save the image file as .png to the filesystem?"

The Python question that I found is: [Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/python-convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem).

Comment: Do the answers to that question help you at all? Or is the other question too specific to Python to help you?

Comment: no. those didnt helped me.

Comment: +1 For caring about question quality and being determined to be a good question asker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because the question title and overal premise is the same, does not *necessarily* make the other question a duplicate. The other question is about how to accomplish the task *with Python*, and that can be a big difference from how to do the same thing *with Java on Android*.

You are encouraged to look at that other question, and see if you can translate the answers over to your own technology. However, it could well be that in this specific case that is not going to work. You are looking for how to do that same thing, but in Java instead with the Android APIs.

So for this *specific* case, go ahead and ask your own question, tagging it with [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [java](/questions/tagged/java). Make sure to include enough information for people to be able to help you (see the [How to ask good quesitons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 6):

The Python answers on the existing question won't help you, so you need to ask it again with the [android](/questions/tagged/android) (and probably [java](/questions/tagged/java)) tag.  Even though it's a partial duplicate, being tagged with a different language should be enough to keep people from voting to close your question.  Make sure to include any research you've already done or code you've already tried in your question.